# Is this the best way to handle static util classes in JS

Tags: javascript, static

I have background in C# I want to add a static utis class to my namespace so that I don't need to create it's instance and use it as a global holder for generic methods, this is what I tried but I am not sure if it's the right way of doing it,

```
var myNameSpace = myNameSpace || {};

myNameSpace.Utils =   {
          a : function () {  // do something... },
          b : function () {  // do something... },
}

window.onload = function () {
            myNameSpace.Utils.a();
}
```

Is this the best way to handle static util classes in JS

Comment: seems alright to me... Can you call the function in a browser console?

Comment: Tried it in a JSFiddle, worked just fine (NB: JSFidlle automatically executes the code "onload", so you can't redefine "window.onload"): 
https://jsfiddle.net/9fhjrh99/

Comment: @PeterFischaleck thanks it was a type mistake on my side, you are right, I slightly changed my question (not sure if I am supposed to do so)

Comment: In this case `window.onload = function () {
            myNameSpace.Utils.a();
}` it looks you would like to override onload function it better to write this one `window.onload = myNameSpace.Utils.a()` am i right ?

Comment: If you really just want to execute `myNameSpace.Utils.a` you could write `window.onload = myNameSpace.Utils.a` (without the parentheses) to asign the function to the onload method, with the parentheses you would asign the return value of the function

Comment: @The I have several other methods that will go into window.onload as well, which is why i wrote it like this, if you think there is any better way please add as answer and i will accept it :)

Comment: `function init(){myNameSpace.Utils.a(); myNameSpace.Utils.b();} windows.onload = init();`  you should create something like this in this case you have to set _init()_ for window.onload